# mysql timestamp showing zero's when record is inseerted

Tags: php, mysql, insert, timestamp

I'm inserting the following php variable into a mysql table,

```
$stamp=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

The MySQL row is configured as type: `timestamp`  default: `current_time`.

When I insert the record my date column shows `0000/00/00 00:00:00`,

after reading other post, it seems that I have the row configured correctly.
apparently im still missing something

Comment: post the table definition and the php code your using to insert

Comment: Apart from what @amdixon wrote, why do you tr to set a timestamp column's value from php code, rather than relying on mysql providing the value?

Comment: type: timestamp default: current_time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
```

Comment: @jermiah the 0's are actually formatted with dashes, my mistake

Comment: lol no, i noticed that you suggested using backslashes, im assuming you suggested that because i initially put back slashes in .this is very weird